# msg.author.dmChannel does not exist

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

so i need to get `msg.author.dmChannel`
it doesnt work
the `msg.author` object is the following:

```
User {
  id: '0000000000000000',
  bot: false,
  system: false,
  flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 0 },
  username: 'username'   ,
  discriminator: '0000',
  avatar: '8eb21315f800000000000000000000008a78ab77e',
  banner: undefined,
  accentColor: undefined
}
```

so there really is no dmChannel? how do i make one? `msg.author.createDM()` doesnt work

EDIT:
`msg.author.send('What is the password?' + '\n If this is not you or you did not use the confim-subscription command please disregard this message. You have 1 minute');` has already been used

```
    msg.author.send('What is the password?' + '\n If this is not you or you did not use the `confim-subscription` command please disregard this message. You have 1 minute');
    console.log(msg.author);
    let channel = msg.author.dmChannel;
    console.log(channel);
      channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == msg.author.id, {
          max: 1,
          time: 60000,
          errors: ['time']
        })
        .then(dm => {
          dm = dm.first()
          if (dm.content == password || dm.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
            dm.channel.send(`Your respone has been processed :thumbsup:`);
            var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member");
            msg.guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles.add(role)
          } else {
            dm.channel.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`)
          }
        })
```

Comment: just curious, whats is the result of "createDM()", ? its should return a dm channel according to the docs
(author is a User btw)
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM

also make sure u have the correct intents, and correct partials (tho i can't remember if those affect cache and stuff, it does affect event receiving.)

Comment: I believe `User.dmChannel` is a getter, meaning it won't be logged. Edit: Yes it is, see [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/structures/User.js#L209)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v13, DMs need their own intent (`DIRECT_MESSAGES`). Also, [`User.dmChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=dmChannel) can be `null`. To force a DM, you can use [`User.createDM`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createDM) which returns the channel. Here is what could be the final code:

```js
let channel = await msg.author.createDM();
channel.send('What is the password?' + '\n If this is not you or you did not use the `confim-subscription` command please disregard this message. You have 1 minute');
      channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == msg.author.id, {
          max: 1,
          time: 60000,
          errors: ['time']
        })
        .then(dm => {
          dm = dm.first()
          if (dm.content == password || dm.content.toUpperCase() == 'Y') {
            dm.channel.send(`Your respone has been processed :thumbsup:`);
            var role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member");
            msg.guild.members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles.add(role)
          } else {
            dm.channel.send(`Terminated: Invalid Response`)
          }
        })
```

Note your client *does* need the DM intents. You can provide it like this:

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES //you can add other intents as needed
    ]
})
```